# Python: problem with reading csv-file on Mac

Tags: python, csv

When I use the following code, the data extracted from file.csv is not comma-separated, but separated with ";". I don't know why this happens, is it something with special with Mac? What can I do about it?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: Have you tried this? data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter=';')

Comment: If you open the file in a text editor, what separators does it have?

Answer (score 0):

You can define which separator to use -

```
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=','))
return data
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the separator like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')
```